# How to properly implement video gallery in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, video, swift

I'm developing a video gallery in iPhone, where the videos are shown on full-screen and you can switch between them with a left/right swipe. The swipe gesture actually initializes a new view, the same view, but with a different video id, and on the new initialized view I'm playing the desired video according to its id.

I have 2 problems with this approach:

1. Switching between videos take a while, probably because it takes some time to initialize a new view, read the video from the file system and start playing it.
2. I can't find how to add a smooth animated movement effect between the videos, like the effect in the native Photos app where you can see both current and next/previous item while swiping (you hold your finger on the screen and the items moves with your finger movement).

Example of my vision can be shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKVUv.png

*(I can't post images unfortunately)*

Does anyone can refer me to some information regarding these questions:

- How does images/videos gallery from this kind are usually built?
- How can I achieve the effect of that movement during the swipe?
- Should I really re-initialize the view or perform some operation in the same view?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found out that I can do something similar using UIScrollView & UIPageControl, is this the right approach?

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

It can be done using UIScrollView - you should add each video as a subview with full-screen size frame to the scrollview, enable paging for it, adjust its contentSize and keep go from there.